# SQL Order by Syntax Error

Tags: android

```
String selectQuery = " select * from BarUpdate where BAR_ADDRESS like %'" +s_area+"'% ORDER BY BAR_NAME";
```

I like to get entire values of address if the given address matched in any of substring of stored address in my application

I got error in both % and orderby

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"SELECT * FROM BarUpdate WHERE BAR_ADDRESS LIKE '%" + s_area + %' ORDER BY BAR_NAME"`?

Comment: cut query from title and post question with format..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String selectQuery = " select * from BarUpdate where BAR_ADDRESS like '% "+ s_area +" %' ORDER BY" + BAR_NAME;
```

Comment: after deleting the order by BAR_NAME it show FATEL EXCEPION IN main and nullpointer exception

Comment: see my updated answer. BAR_NAME and query, is it reside in same class?